# Read SOAP response php

Tags: php, soap

I have a SoapClient with PHP and I can't read the string response, I tried to use different methods that I found in this forum but nothing works.

This is my response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns0:Update_REGISTRYResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:DATA_BMC_CORE_REGISTRY_Modify" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ns0:InstanceId>OI-291D85EF140A464EA9E7CA6918D1A4C7</ns0:InstanceId>
<ns0:Numero_REGISTRY>0712</ns0:Numero_REGISTRY>
```

And my code in PHP is:

```
$soap     = simplexml_load_string($soapResponse);
        $response = $soap->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children()->Update_REGISTRYResponse;
        $customerId = (string) $response->Update_ATMResponse->Numero_REGISTRY;
        echo $customerId;
```

And the result is:

> **Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in

But exist the string in my `$soapResponse`;